# Como dar escape de uma variável javascript para o blade do Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Olá, tenho essa função javascript que recebe um parametro:

```
function teste(id){
  document.getElementById("campo1").innerHTML = id;
  document.getElementById("campo2").innerHTML = {{app\User::find("id")->titulo}}
}
```

Como eu faço para que a função User::find() pegue a variável 'id' que é do javascript, existe alguma forma de se fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possivel a função `teste(id)` roda em tempo de execução no front-end, o `{{app\User::find("id")->titulo}}` é Blade que por sua vez é parte do Laravel que é um framework PHP e roda no back-end é processado e entregue a front-end já pronto.

Então não tem como fazer isto e *nem é uma coisa lógica* de se fazer, o melhor seja mudar a estratégia, mas vai depender do que `User::find("id")->titulo` tem que fazer e o que o `teste()` realmente faz. Do jeito que esta fica difícil dar uma alternativa.

Comment: Valeu Guilherme, a questão do blade rodar no back-end sanou a minha dúvida.